# Close program by opened by her file

Tags: java, cmd, process

How to close the process programmaticaly (Java) by opened by her file. For exemple, i have some file named **notes.txt**. He is opening programmatically (using Java, but for ask i used CMD) over default program for *txt-files*, in my case it is **Notepad** and thereby it is creating new process named *Notepad:*
[image]
[image]

As you can see, i have one more process **Notepad** with an open file **data.txt.**

How can i programmatically complete process **Notepad** with file **notes.txt** so that **data.txt** is stays, using *CMD* or maybe some *Java* tools.

How to do it? Maybe i should get default program for opening the *txt-files* (and further other extensions) and then to do something with them...
In general, i need any ideas...

*Thanks in advance. Regards...*

Comment: Each process has an ID associated with, you can kill that process with id.

Comment: How can I get an ID programmatically (using Java), if I only know path of the file.

Answer (score 1):

Since you know the Window Titles, for example:

```
data.txt - Notepad
notes.txt - Notepad
```

then you can use the Window's **taskkill** utility:

```
try {
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    rt.exec("taskkill /F /FI \"WINDOWTITLE eq notes.txt - Notepad\" /T");
} 
catch (IOException | SecurityException | IllegalArgumentException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Ultimately, if **notes.txt** and **data.txt** are open then notes.txt will be closed.

Comment: Good option but not universal. Not all programs have a name of the opened file in the title bar. As I have already said, in my program there are only paths to the files with which I must operate.